# Primefaces: Add a new row to datatable gives error: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have a datatable where I want to add a new row. When doing so I get the following error
javax.servlet.ServletException: DataModel must implement org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModel when selection is enabled.

How can I solve my problem?

This is in my xhtml

```
<h:commandLink  action="#{workOrderDetail.addOrderItem}" >
        <img src="${path.staticRootUrl}images/add.png" border="0" alt="${msg.workorderdetail_neworderitem}" title="${msg.workorderdetail_neworderitem}"/>
     </h:commandLink>
<p:dataTable styleClass="ptable100" id="orderItems" var="orderItem" value="#{workOrderDetail.orderItems}" width="100%" height="200" widgetVar="results"
     emptyMessage="#{msg.all_lists_no_records_found}" selection="#{workOrderDetail.selectedOrderItem}" selectionMode="single" onRowSelectUpdate=":detail:sub"
     rowKey="#{orderItem.id}"
<p:ajax event="rowSelect"  update=":detail:sub" />
```

and this is my bean code

```
List<IMWSOrderItem> orderList = null;
public void addOrderItem() throws MWSException {
  IMWSOrderItem newOrderItem = getWorkOrder().getMWSOrder().getMWSOrderItem_Set().getNewMWSOrderItem();      
  getWorkOrder().getMWSOrder().getMWSOrderItem_Set().addMWSOrderItem(newOrderItem);
  orderList = null;   
}
public List<IMWSOrderItem> getOrderItems() throws MWSException {
  if (orderList == null) {
     orderList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(getWorkOrder().getMWSOrder().getMWSOrderItem_Set().getMWSOrderItems()));
  }
  return orderList;
}
public IMWSOrderItem getSelectedOrderItem() {
  return selectedOrderItem;
}
public void setSelectedOrderItem(IMWSOrderItem newSelectedOrderItem) {
  this.selectedOrderItem = newSelectedOrderItem;
}
```

Comment: Which PF version? Setting the `rowKey` attribute to point to the unique identifier of the `var` object should solve it, but you already have set it.

Comment: PrimeFaces 3.2. I know, I had to add it because at first the row selection didn't work. But that is working fine now. Displaying the details of every row in a separate section on the page. But when adding a new row it fails. strange.

Comment: Ok, found the problem. When adding a new item, its ID is default to null and the id is used as rowkey. So I initialized the id to -1 when adding a new one and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. When adding a new item, its ID is default to null and the id is used as rowkey. So I initialized the id to -1 when adding a new one and it works.

Comment: Just  a related word of caution: I used this solution (which is not "per se" bad) and then some months later have noticed it can cause a problem if used (too naively) with JPA entities. If an entity already has an id allocated (such as -1), it can mess up an explicit persist or a cascade persist. I ended up with one entity Class in fact getting just 1 persisted instance (so it looked like cross-talk between "entities" in the JSF layer), and I got some JPA errors due to it thinking that there was already an entity with -1. Quick solution was to check for -1 then force it `null` before persist.

Comment: Using exposed `hashCode()` works for me (although not sure whether has security consequences; I am using a hashCode generation utility anyway). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797241/using-rowkey-in-primefaces-datatable-with-new-entity

Answer (score 1):

No need to set the id to -1, just write a function like:

`public int getRowKey(Integer id) {
        return id!=null?id:-1;
    }`

and call it from an el expression in @rowKey