# Using rowKey in primefaces dataTable with new entity

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Well, I know that i must choose a field from my object that is unique, like a ID. Then my rowKey is "item.id". This works fine when load all itens in a dataTable, but if I add a new item (this object didn't persisted in database yet) with null ID, it don't apper in my dataTable.

What is the solution for this ? I just can use ID as a rowKey but sometimes i need add a new object with NULL ID (because this is didn't persisted on database yet).

Look my code:

```
<p:dataTable rowKey="#{item.id}" var="item"
                    value="#{orcamentoMB.itens}"
                    emptyMessage="Não foi encontrado nenhum registro"
                    id="dataTableItens"
                    selection="#{orcamentoMB.selectedItemOrcamento}"
                    selectionMode="single" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                    rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'first-row' : 'second-row'}">
```

Answer (score 12):

Use another unique identifier then. Perhaps the `hashCode()` or even the `toString()`?

```
rowKey="#{not empty item.id ? item.id : item.hashCode()}"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using EL 2.2, so that you can't call methods, you can create a method in your Item class for obtaining a unique ID to be used as rowKey, for instance:

```
public int getRowKey() { return this.hashCode(); }
```

And then you can use in the JSF page:

```
rowKey="#{item.rowKey}"
```

Comment: I like this idea of exposing  `hashCode()`  via a separate getter like `getRowKey()`, because it hides the choice of key strategy somewhat (so `getRowKey()` acts as API), and gives slightly easier EL access.

Comment: It should be int or Integer also, in the return type?

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer, but a comment to proposed solutions.

Keep in mind that you may end up with non unique rowKeys. For that reason I decided to use -1 as rowkey for a new row and to accept only one new row at the time, hope this helps.

Comment: Which solution? This is not answer but most likely should have been a comment

Comment: Sorry I cannot comment don't have +50

Comment: Then please gain 50 rep. You can easily by editing Q or A and gain +2 for each edit. Answers are for answers not comments. Now it is unclear where it relates to. The question or another answer