# Primefaces datatable onEdit() edits the wrong entry if an entry has been added before refreshing the view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

i've got a question concerning Primefaces (version 5.0) and their datatable.
If I have a p:datatable and I want to edit a cell or row (doesn't matter - behaviour is the same in that case) AND someone added a new entry to that database, I edit the new entry instead of the old.

Well. Here are some code-snippets:

my index.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="viewChanges">
  <p:dataTable id="changeTable" 
             widgetVar="changeTable"
             value="#{changeController.list}" var="item"
             selection="#{changeController.selectedChangeEntry}"
             selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{item.id}"
             sortBy="#{item.id}" sortOrder="descending"
             editable="#{lDAPUserController.loggedIn}" 
             style="width: auto">

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" 
                        listener="#{changeController.onRowEdit}" 
                        update=":growlInfo, :growlError, :viewChanges:changeTable" />

                         ..output of columns..

                <p:column style="width:32px">
                    <p:rowEditor />
                </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

my changeController.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "changeController")
@ViewScoped
public class ChangeController implements java.io.Serializable {

    attributes, getter, setter, other methods etc..

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) { 
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Change Edited", ((Change) event.getObject()).getId());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

Well with this it's already possible to replicate the error.
Little Example: We have a dataset with 3 entries. - id=1,2,3

We open a browser[1] and see the 3 datasets. We now open a private tab[2] and go to the same site and add a new entry. Without refreshing [1] we edit the entry with id=3. All of the sudden we edited entry with id=4.

Could someone explain me why this is happening? Is it me or is it bug in primefaces? Wrong Scope?

Comment: I have not yet seen this happening using different tabs, windows or even different browsers (thereby different sessions).

Comment: I can't replicate it using different browsers (somehow) - only if I use two completely different clients or one browser in private mode.

Comment: Based on what you're describing, the bug would have to be in `ViewScoped`: if PrimeFaces is working in one client but not another, there is no interaction between the two PrimeFaces, so a PF bug doesn't make sense. It's very unlikely that you've found a bug in `ViewScoped`, and it should only be imagined after all other possibilities have been exhausted. I suspect there is a bug in your code, perhaps your use of `rowKey`, which seems to be [a common source of errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797241/using-rowkey-in-primefaces-datatable-with-new-entity).

Comment: It also appears in other scopes and my rowKey is the Object-ID which is persisted in the database.