# JSF Multiple Concurrent Clients

Tags: jsf, primefaces, concurrency, datatable

I have a Primefaces 6 + Spring 3 integrated web app with a simple cell-editable Primefaces datatable bound to a (Spring) session-scoped backing bean that populates the datatable model object from a SQL query, pretty standard stuff. Cell edits trigger an ajax call that updates the database. It works great with a single user and passed all my single-user system tests.

After deploy to production I find that when more than one user has the app open, cell edits go completely whacko. Sometimes the edit makes it to the database but the cell in the UI lapses back to the non-edited value. Sometimes the new value shows up in the wrong row in the display, even though the page was not refreshed.

I am dimly aware that the model object in user1's backing bean becomes dirty when user2 makes an edit, so that when user1 subsequently makes an edit things might go awry, but the failure happens even when user1 makes no edits at all. I have implemented no mechanism for pushing data from the server to clients after an edit to keep clients in sync.

Each row in the datatable corresponds to a distinct object with a (hidden) ID from the corresponding column in the database. Because of this my obviously misguided thinking was that SQL updates would apply to the correct database row regardless of how stale the displayed data is, but they do not.

The query has no "order by" and the code does not sort the results, so I thought perhaps different HTTP requests and subsequent query executions return the rows in different orders, but I verified that they do not.

I thought perhaps scoping the backing bean to application scope might resolve the issue but this would not solve the problem that user1's displayed table has gotten out of sync after user2 makes an edit.

This seems like a fundamental problem with a simple solution that simply escapes me. Is this a situation where Ajax is strictly verboten?

Comment: Just found (too late) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30917122/primefaces-datatable-onedit-edits-the-wrong-entry-if-an-entry-has-been-added-b) that addresses the same situation, no solution for me. I am using Spring in conjunction with JSF so ViewScope is not available, but apparently this is not a solution anyway. I have been able to update the entire row after an edit, so the editor can see any concurrent edits made by others in other columns, but this does not resolve the issue of the rows being out of order.

Comment: Hi @snakedog, welcome to SO ;). I think you should try including some new pieces to solve this issue. Refresh the table for logged in users after a few seconds, or maybe use sockets to notify the browser and then refresh the displayed records. Also, you could include versioning in your database's records, this way you can make sure that no one will update a unsynced value. And last, but not less important, keep your users always up to date with realtime feedback of the actual data being loaded and persisted, thus preventing any undesired input being persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, @Bonifacio. Those are great items of advice, I appreciate them. In my case, the records being edited are only 4 small Strings, so comparing the data currently being displayed with the results of another query at ajax submit time is not onerous. For this reason I elected not to incorporate the complexity of push notifications, as well, although that is a much more robust solution. Last, this is a rarely used admin app, so subjecting users to an even rarer experience of having to re-enter data made sense. But in general your suggestions are I think best practice.